# passing the query value to mail template in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I want to pass the query value and get the value in mail template.I want to pass data as ['users'=>$users] .I caught internal server error

```
controller

$users = DB::table('travel_request')
        ->join('department', 'travel_request.department_id', '=', 'department.id')
        ->join('users', 'travel_request.approver_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('travel_purpose', 'travel_request.travel_purpose_id', '=', 'travel_purpose.id')
        ->join('traveling_details', 'travel_request.id','=','traveling_details.travel_request_id' )
        ->join('country','country.id', '=', 'traveling_details.country_id')
        ->join('travel_type','traveling_details.travel_type_id', '=', 'travel_type.id')
        ->join('travel_request_status','travel_request.status_id', '=', 'travel_request_status.id')
        ->select('travel_request.*', 'travel_request.id as travel_id','department.name as dept_name','users.firstname as approver_name','travel_purpose.purpose','country.name as country_name','traveling_details.from_date','traveling_details.to_date','travel_request_status.status','travel_type.type as travelType')->where('travel_request.id',$id)->get(); 

      Mail::Send('email.welcome', $users, function($message) use($users)  {
        $message->to('sample.demo@domain.com', 'Travel Request')->subject
        ('Testing Mail');
        $message->from('sampele2.sample@demo.com','dummyname');
    });   


 welcome.blade.php
 @foreach ($users as $user)
    {{$user->traveler_name}}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Check your logs, what does it say? `app/storage/logs` for laravel 4, `storage/logs` for laravel 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below

```
$data['users'] =$users;
Mail::Send('email.welcome', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
   $message->to('sample.test@domain.com', 'Travel Request')->subject
        ('Testing Mail');
   $message->from('ample.test@domain.com','dummy text');
});


welcome.blade.php
 @foreach ($users as $user)
    {{$user->traveler_name}}
 @endforeach
```

This is just for notification.